# Why structures are Serializable in .net?

Tags: vb.net, structure, serializable

```
<Serializable()> Public Structure structResult
    Public ResultID As Integer
    Public SurveyID As Integer
    Public QuestionID As Integer
    Public AnswerID As Integer
    Public Text As String

    Public ModifierID As Integer
    Public ModifiedDate As DateTime
End Structure
```

Comment: why structures are serializing in .net?

Comment: What is your question : " Why my structure is serializable  ? " ???

Comment: yes generally why structures  are serializing in project? what is the advantage by serializing this structures

Comment: Just to be clear; you understand what Serialization is, yes?  If so, then you already know the answer to your question.  If not, I suggest you read up on the subject.  It's a handy technique, and essential for distributed systems.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is useful for saving objects :

- In files or other persistent storage.
  Useful for restoring the state of an application.
- In socket streams for sending an object from a client to a server (or reverse).

Serialization is also interesting because it allows to save object graphs quite easily.

For instance a Car has an Engine.
When the Car is saved, the Engine is also saved

`Structures` can be serialized, but also `classes` of course.

The serialization you show in your code excerpt uses standard CLR serialization.
But there is also `DataContractSerializer` with the  and  attributes, and some few more (JSON.Net, ...)

Regards